# RealTek RTL8723AE Wireless Lan 802.11n PCI-E NIC

Tags: wireless-networking

I have a Toshiba C850 with the above wireless card.Continually on boot up it will not connect automatically and I have to trouble shoot to resolve problem. When scan is completed it advises that the wireless card was reset. I have tried updating driver but no improvement. Is it possible to replace the card with an alternative and would this resolve problem. If so are there any recommendations. I am running Windows 7. Thanks, KBO1937.

Answer (score 0):

Find out what size the current card is, there are different heights, and then you can order one to replace it.

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Intel-Dual-Band-Wireless-AC-7260/dp/B00E7QGHE6/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1400154621&sr=8-1&keywords=intel+wireless+mini+card

That'd be an upgrade. Has AC.

This should show you where the card is and how to get access to it:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=14ON-vDgMhI